# if element is displayed > hide all elements underneath it (plain JS)

Tags: javascript

My goal is to detect if my element is displayed firstly; I guess narrowed down to `display: block;`.

If it is; I'd like to iterate through all the elements ***underneath it*** within the document to add classes to them. The elements are dynamic; so I just need to add a common selector so that I can hide them (or `display: none;`) them - when my first element's `display: block;` is met.

Below is what I have; I'm mainly wondering how to detect if elements are underneath `#banner` > if so add a common selector (class) to them so that I can then hide (`display:none;`)

```
   function CheckIfExistThenHideBelow () {  
        var inElgbl =  document.getElementById('banner');
        if (typeof(inElgbl) != 'undefined' && inElgbl != null)
        { 
        // How to check if below element inElgbl in doc?

        var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("below"); 

        for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should maybe Just add a css class to the parent node with a rule to show/hide all Child nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than you think. Just loop over the target element's siblings that come after it and hide each by applying a class.

```js
function removeSiblingsAfter(someElement){    

    // Check some element to see if it is currently being displayed as a block
    if(getComputedStyle(someElement).display === "block"){

       // Begin looping while there is a next sibling that is an element
       while(someElement.nextElementSibling){
         // Adjust the looping variable to be the next sibling
         // so that the loop can eventually end
         someElement = someElement.nextElementSibling; 
         
         someElement.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide each sibling
       }
    }
}

removeSiblingsAfter(document.getElementById("sampleTarget"));
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div>Sibling Before<div>
<div id="sampleTarget">Target Element</div>
<div>Sibling After</div>
<div>
   <a href="http://example.com">Sibling After</a>
</div>
<div>Sibling After</div>
```

Comment: @No-Spex I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: The element isn't a parent element; it doesn't have children

Comment: @No-Spex Please see updated answer. Your original question wasn't clear as "underneath" often means "children". But, it appears you meant "siblings" that come after.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! @Scott

Comment: @No-Spex No problem. If my answer solved it for your, please up vote it and mark it as "the" answer.